# Conversion failed. SELECT * from Person.Address WHERE ISNUMERIC(PostalCode) =1 AND PostalCode<7000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

It is Microsoft SQL Server.

In this column `PostalCode` from the AdventureWorks 2012 `Person.Address` table, there are numeric and string values.

I want to get table with rows `WHERE PostalCode < 7000`

This does not work as expected:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]

SELECT *
FROM Person.Address
WHERE ISNUMERIC(PostalCode) = 1 
  AND PostalCode < 7000
```

because I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'K4B 1T7' to data type int.

I can make it, by creating temporally table like this:

```
/* creating of temp table */
USE AdventureWorks2012

SELECT * 
INTO temp2
FROM Person.Address
WHERE ISNUMERIC(PostalCode) = 1

/* get data from temp table */
SELECT * 
FROM temp2
WHERE PostalCode < 7000
```

But it is a bad way, cause of low productivity and needless temp-table.

What is the better way to get table with rows `WHERE PostalCode < 7000` but data has not only numeric values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is being returned because the conditions being evaluated are not short-circuiting - the condition `PostalCode<7000` is being evaluated even where the postal code is non-numeric.

Instead, try:

```
SELECT *
from Person.Address
WHERE CASE WHEN PostalCode NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
           THEN CAST(PostalCode AS NUMERIC)
           ELSE CAST(NULL AS NUMERIC) 
      END <7000
```

(Updated following comments)

Comment: Nice one. That 7001 makes the difference!

Comment: @juan that part could have been excluded. That would have compared null < 7000 which returns false

Comment: NULL might be a better choice for the `ELSE` in case the `7000` condition changes (or becomes a variable).

Comment: `Isnumeric` has way too many drawbacks even your answer will fail when there is record like `1e1`,`$100`,..

Comment: why not replace the ISNUMERIC with PATINDEX with regex for 4 integers

Comment: `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

[link](http://finalbird.com/questions/syntax_error.png)[/link]

Comment: Or you can use `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` to filter for all digits.

Answer (score 5):

If you're in SQL Server 2012 or newer you should use try_convert instead of isnumeric. Isnumeric has some funny issues that it returns 1 even for strings that can't be converted into a number. So something like this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person.Address
WHERE try_convert(int, PostalCode) < 7000
```

If the string can't be converted, try_convert returns null.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx

Comment: Actually at home it is 2012, but at work it is 2008 version of MSSQL. So, for  2012+ version I think it is the best decision of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The text is from 70-461 Training kit
([Exam 70-461: Querying Microsoft SQL Server 2012](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/training-kit-exam-70-461-querying-microsoft-sql-server-9780735666054)):

> Recall from Chapter 1 that all expressions that appear in the same
> logical query processing phase—for example, the WHERE phase—are
> conceptually evaluated at the same point in time. For example,
> consider the following filter predicate.

```
WHERE propertytype = 'INT' AND CAST(propertyval AS INT) > 10
```

> Suppose that the table being queried
> holds different property values. The propertytype column represents
> the type of the property (an INT, a DATE, and so on), and the
> propertyval column holds the value in a character string. When
> propertytype is 'INT', the value in propertyval is convertible to INT;
> otherwise, not necessarily.
>
> Some assume that unless precedence rules
> dictate otherwise, predicates will be evaluated from left to right,
> and that short circuiting will take place when possible. In other
> words, if the first predicate propertytype = 'INT' evaluates to false,
> SQL Server won’t evaluate the second predicate CAST(propertyval AS
> INT) > 10 because the result is already known. Based on this
> assumption, the expectation is that the query should never fail trying
> to convert something that isn’t convertible.
>
> The reality, though, is
> different. SQL Server does internally support a short-circuit concept;
> however, due to the all-at-once concept in the language, it is not
> necessarily going to evaluate the expressions in left-to-right order.
> It could decide, based on cost-related reasons, to start with the
> second expression, and then if the second expression evaluates to
> true, to evaluate the first expression as well. This means that if
> there are rows in the table where propertytype is different than
> 'INT', and in those rows propertyval isn’t convertible to INT, the
> query can fail due to a conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

The only safe way of doing this is by getting first the Ids of the fields you are interested in and then join with them in different statements, otherwise the query planner could decide it want to do first the numeric comparison. I started to get a lot of this problems when we upgraded to SQL Server 2008 that didn't happened before.

You can however do a conversion:

```
USE [AdventureWorks2012]
SELECT *
from Person.Address
WHERE ISNUMERIC(PostalCode) =1 AND CAST(CAST(PostalCode AS INT) AS VARCHAR)<'7000'
```

I have done the castings to try to avoid any data that could be numeric but with 0 padding on the left that could screw up the ordering.

Beware that the performance of this won't be the best and Indexes on PostalCode aren't going to be used.

Comment: RIght, damn string sortering. You must add 0s on the left to make them have the same width. But It think it would be better if you for @Mark Bannister solution

Answer (score 0):

Here in Denmark, postal code always have the same length, so I would use this script to avoid strange issues* with isnumeric and conversion issues.
It will check that postalCode has 4 digits and compare the string value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM temp2
WHERE
  PostalCode < '7000' and
  PostalCode like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

*An example of strange issues with isnumeric

```
SELECT isnumeric('£1.1')
SELECT isnumeric('-')
```

Both returns 1

Comment: You can filter them using `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'`

Comment: @wewesthemenace wouldn't that give the same result ?

Comment: @SamAniston - Don't use ISNUMERIC answers suggested by others either use `NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'` to filter the bad records or this answer

Comment: @t-clausen.dk, I'm just pointing out that the "issues" with `ISNUMERIC` could be replace by that predicate. That would return only rows with all-digit characters.

Answer (score -1):

You can use subquery to do that :

```
    select * from ( 
     SELECT * from Person.Address WHERE ISNUMERIC(PostalCode) =1 ) t 
     where PostalCode<7000
```

Comment: The optimizer can evaluate this as `ISNUMERIC(PostalCode) = 1 AND PostalCode < 7000` and will return the same error.

Comment: @wewesthemenace - Not sure how a optimizer can combine the outer query filter and inner query filter together.

Comment: @NoDisplayName - See this comment by Aaron Bertrand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420508/check-if-field-is-numeric-then-execute-comparison-on-only-those-field-in-one-st#comment18340395_13420557

Comment: I've also tested it in my local machine, and it returns the same error.

Comment: @NoDisplayName -The optimizer does not necessarily combine the condition, but it may rewrite it such that the `PostalCode < 7000` is evaluated first before the `ISNUMERIC`.

Comment: @wewesthemenace i just try it and there is no way for me, where the optimizer will combine outer query and inner query filter ..

Comment: Please read this excellent explanation by Aaron Bertrand: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420508/check-if-field-is-numeric-then-execute-comparison-on-only-those-field-in-one-st#comment18340943_13420557. Basically, the optimizer might opt to evaluate the `<` first before the `ISNUMERIC`

Comment: THE SAME ERROR:
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'K4B 1T7' to data type int.

Comment: Yea, wewesthemenace explained it pretty nicely :) didnt know that, thank you