# SQL Server Conversion error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'XXX' to data type int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Running some pretty simple SQL here:

```
select * 
from table
where columnA <> convert(int,columnB)
  and isnumeric(columnB) = 1
```

Still getting this error every time:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'XXX' to data type int.

Comment: What are the data types of columnA and columnB? This error could be thrown if columnA contains 'XXX'

Comment: Does [this question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420508/check-if-field-is-numeric-then-execute-comparison-on-only-those-field-in-one-st) help you?    Perhaps putting your convert inside of a case statement would help.

Comment: One more thing, If you have a decimal in columnB it will pass isnumeric() but still fail on your convert to integer. You need extra measure to verify it is an integer.

Comment: Thanks @Chris both comments are spot on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this using a combination of the answers and comments here. I used a `CASE` statement in my `WHERE` clause and also had to use `LIKE` instead of `ISNUMERIC` to account for illegal characters. I also had to use `BIGINT` because a few select samples were overflowing the `INT` column. Thanks for all of the suggestions everybody!

```
select * from patient
where PatientExternalID <> 
    (case when mrn not like '%[^0-9]%'
          then convert(bigint, mrn) 
       else 0 
    end)
```

Comment: What about `'.'` in columnB ;).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SQL Server 2012 or more recent you could use `TRY_PARSE` which will return `NULL` when the parse fails.

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE('one' as int)   -- NULL
     , TRY_PARSE('1' as int)     -- 1
     , TRY_PARSE('0.1' as int)   -- NULL
```

> Returns the result of an expression, translated to the requested data type, or null if the cast fails in SQL Server. Use TRY_PARSE only for converting from string to date/time and number types.

Answer (score 0):

Isnumeric has a lot of odd behavior. For example, it also considers currency signs such as $ or £, and even a hyphen (-) to be numeric.

I think you'd be better of using

```
NOT columnB like '%[^0-9]%'
```

to ONLY take numbers into account.

Check the comments at the bottom of the msdn page for isnumeric(), which you can find here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx

Comment: When I run that condition alone, I get the result set I expect, but when I add the comparison with the conversion as the 2nd condition, it is still trying to convert values that failed the first condition for some reason.

Comment: Either columnA is non numeric or the query planner has decided to do the comparison before the like

Comment: I'm gonna test something and I'll get back to you in 2 minutes before I post a wrong suggestiong :)

Comment: As I suspected, your where clause doesn't check for COLUMNB to be a number. 
Basically you're saying "Select all data where the conversion to an integer of column B is different than column A, and where ColumnB is a number.

So you're gonna attempt to convert non-numeric value into an integer.

Try indeed working with a subquery to first check whether or not you should actually apply the conversion, before applying it.

Comment: What about `'.'` in columnB ;).

Answer (score 0):

This may sound weird, but it breaks when do not put the ISNUMERIC check first. Try this out:

```
WITH [Table]
AS
(
    SELECT columnA,columnB
    FROM
    (
        VALUES  (1,'2'),
                (2,'XXX')
    ) A(columnA,columnB)
)

select *
from [Table]
where       ISNUMERIC(columnB) = 1          --this works
        AND columnA <> convert(int,columnB)

--where     columnA <> convert(int,columnB) --this doesn't work
--      and isnumeric(columnB) = 1
```

Comment: What about `'.'` in columnB ;).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to reverse your checking like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE CONVERT(NVARCHAR, columnA) <> columnB
```